# How to add banner above 'Auto hiding navbar on scroll down'?

Tags: jquery, css, menu, sticky

I found a great auto hiding navbar but I don't know how to correctly add static banner above it. Can anyone help?

Navbar demo:

https://codepen.io/Mhmdhasan/pen/mAdaQE

Navbar script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  'use strict';

   var c, currentScrollTop = 0,
       navbar = $('nav');

   $(window).scroll(function () {
      var a = $(window).scrollTop();
      var b = navbar.height();

      currentScrollTop = a;

      if (c < currentScrollTop && a > b + b) {
        navbar.addClass("scrollUp");
      } else if (c > currentScrollTop && !(a <= b)) {
        navbar.removeClass("scrollUp");
      }
      c = currentScrollTop;
  });

});
```

Comment: Is the banner supposed to auto-hide too? Or stay permanently at the top?

Comment: @corschdi OP mentions static.

Comment: @corschdi Banner should not be sticked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a fixed-height banner by just adding a `div` element before your `nav` element. The navbar's css has to be adapted to match the height of the banner's `div`.

You can then use

```
$('.banner').height()
```

to calculate the additional scrolling height for the navigation bar to disappear.

Working example (or on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mYvaNx)):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  'use strict';
  
   var c, currentScrollTop = 0,
       banner = $('.banner'),
       navbar = $('nav');

   $(window).scroll(function () {
      var a = $(window).scrollTop();
     
      if (a > banner.height()) {
        navbar.addClass("fixed");
      } else {
        navbar.removeClass("fixed");
      }
     
      var b = navbar.height() + banner.height();
     
      currentScrollTop = a;
     
      if (c < currentScrollTop && a > b + b) {
        navbar.addClass("scrollUp");
      } else if (c > currentScrollTop && !(a <= b)) {
        navbar.removeClass("scrollUp");
      }
      c = currentScrollTop;
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 3000px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.banner {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  clear: both;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav {
  background: #fff;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9998;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
nav.fixed {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
nav.scrollUp {
  transform: translateY(-180px);
}
nav ul.navbar-menu {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
nav ul.navbar-menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
nav ul.navbar-menu li a {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 14px;
}
nav a#brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  foat: left;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav button {
  background: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: none;
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
nav button span {
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  nav ul.navbar-menu {
    display: none;
  }

  nav button {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="banner">
  Banner content
</div>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" id="brand">Brand</a>
    <button>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </button>
    
    <ul class="navbar-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">page a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">page b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">page c</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">page d</a></li>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answer. I will use your solution for other purpose but primarily I don't want this banner to be sticked. How to do it?

Comment: @Avigo I updated my answer to make the banner non-sticky.

Answer (score 1):

why do not use `position: sticky` for your banner element?
for example:

```css
.banner { 
position: sticky;
top: 20px;
}
```

here is demo online: https://codepen.io/zq-jhon/pen/QRYoyK